# Carbon diffForHumans cant use in laravel 5.5?

Tags: laravel, php-carbon, laravel-5.6

first I  use Carbon\Carbon; then I try to echo difforhumans reference by doc : https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff

```
echo Carbon::parse('2019-08-03')->diffForHumans('2019-08-13');
```

laravel 5.5 said Parse error: syntax error,

**UPDATE**

I install laravel 5.6 but I downgrade into 5.5

here is my full code

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        dd(\Carbon\Carbon::parse('2019-08-03')->diffForHumans('2019-08-13'));

    }
```

[image]

Comment: please be more detailed about the errors and the sources.

Comment: where did you use this?? show your full code

Comment: I just use it in Controller

Comment: could you please show your full code

Comment: ok 'll update my full code

Comment: i updated my full code

Comment: which PHP version are you using? Nullable Types ("?string") require at least PHP 7.1

Comment: wa i use version 7.0 thanks  @maxwilms

Comment: @test131 show your full controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `diffForHumans` don't take any arguments.If just removing  the date from `diffForHumans` won't work..

Try this:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        dd(Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d','2019-08-03')->diffForHumans());

    }
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that i could help

Answer (score 0):

That is the proper way:

```
echo \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2019-08-03')->diffForHumans(\Carbon\Carbon::parse('2019-08-13'));
```

The error you propably got was:

Argument 1 passed to Carbon\Carbon::diffForHumans() must be an instance of Carbon\Carbon, string given

It means that function "`parse`" needed proper `Carbon` data format.

Comment: still get same error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: i try to use : dd(\Carbon\Carbon::parse('2019-08-03')->diffForHumans('2019-08-13'));

Comment: that is the error? Type error: Argument 1 passed to Carbon\Carbon::diffForHumans() must be an instance of Carbon\Carbon, string given

Comment: look now please

Comment: noting it's just show Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError thrown with message "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)"

Stacktrace:
#0 Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError in /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/translation/Translator.php:79

Comment: check also your app language settings, I got by echo: 1 week before, try echo \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2019-08-03')->diffForHumans(\Carbon\Carbon::parse('2019-08-13'));

Comment: still get same error, I forgot I used laravel 5.6 then I drowngrad into 5.5 version

Answer (score 0):

### Pass `NULL` in `diffForHumans()` and use Class `Carbon`

```
dd(Carbon::parse('2019-08-03')->diffForHumans());
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic way to do it like this:

```php
dd(\Carbon\Carbon::parse('2019-08-03')->diffForHumans());
```

If you are retrieving a date from the database you can change it to be like this:

```php
dd(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($user->created_at)->diffForHumans());
```

while `user->created_at` creates the date you get from tables.